# Nash Demand Game

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I've got a question to ask about the Nash Demand game from my assignment.

> Sarah and Ruth find \$100 on the ground and decide to split it between them in the following manner. Each individual simultaneously and independently selects how much of the \$100 she wants to keep. Denote this value by . If +≤100, then each player receives the amount she desires. If +>100, they forfeit the \$100, and each player receives \$0. Find all of the Nash equilibria. Explain how you come to your conclusion (i.e. how you know that your answer is exhaustive.)

I'm quite lost as to how to even start the question. Thanks in advance to anyone! :)

Comment: I suggest making sure you know what an equilibrium is, and then start picking numbers until you see a pattern. For example, "Sarah chooses \$30 and Ruth chooses \$80" is not an equilibrium. This is because--in this 30-80 case--they throw the money away, but Sarah (or Ruth) could do better by choosing a difference number. _If Sarah knew Ruth_ would pick \$80, Sarah would be better off choosing something other than \$30, like \$15, thereby getting \$15 instead of \$0.

Comment: I see. I have thought about it and I realised the Best response of each player is just 100-xR or 100-xS assuming the other player chooses xR and xS respectively. Now I'm trying to figure out about the mixed strategy nash equilibrium! Thanks so much! :)